# Delete Certificate From Azure Key Vault? Does this delete Cert Resource types?

Tags: azure, certificate, azure-keyvault, side-effects

I have a certificate that needs to be deleted. But it is currently assigned out to several Microsoft.Web resources. When the cert was assigned, Microsoft.Web/Certificate resources were created.

My question: When I use the [Delete Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/deletecertificate/deletecertificate) command, does this delete all the spawned Microsoft.Web/Certificate resources or just the contents of the Key Vault? The documentation does not make it clear as to what happens.

Comment: When you say "Assigned out to several Microsoft.Web Resources" what exactly does that mean? Per the description of the documentation it says "Deletes a certificate from a specified key vault".

Comment: @FrankHuMSFT The documentation says more than just that. Please refer to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I test it for you, it will not delete the `Microsoft.Web/Certificate` resource.

In the resource explorer before deleting the certificate:

[image]

In my keyvault before deleting the certificate:

[image]

After deleting it, the `Microsoft.Web/Certificate` is still existing like the first screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Joy, you might want to correct that last image to show the azure.resource site instead. That supports your statement better. :)